# Excel formula over multiple sheets

Tags: excel-formula, multiple-columns

I created a workbook where multiple people track their numbers on a weekly basis. There is a tab for each month here is an example:

```
Person A, week 1, value
          week 2, value
          week 3, value
          week 4, value
Person B, week 1, value
          week 2, value
          week 3, value
          week 4, value
```

This repeats for multiple sheets and multiple people. I'm looking to do a summary that would be like this:

```
Person A, Value
Person B, Value
```

I have been able to do it individually and create a formula across multiple sheets. However, when dragging the formula down it only shifts the range by 1. Is there a way to adjust so when I drag the formula it sums up the next set of data value? So when i drag the formula down in the summary it shifts to cover all person's be data points and mix in A and B?

So i would expect if on the first row it was the sum Person A's week 1-4, when I drag the formula to the 2nd row of the summary it would sum all of Person B's data points.

Comment: Sample code/sceenshots -so we're not left in the dark trying to fathom exactly what you're after mate ta

Comment: ctrl + t in respective sheets to convert to a table.

Options/tools (?) to remove option "use Table names in the formula"

Ctrl + shift + page up/down as required to select/highight all tabs in question 

i DON;T get the ~Q otheise unortuany; but at least you know that ctrl ; insets date (in most office applications including excel, pp I believe:)

Comment: Use a Pivot Table. There are lots of free tutorials on the web.